# Setting CORS call to GET not OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, authorization, cors

I am creating a CORS call as follows:

```
createCORSRequest: function(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        console.log("Sending request with credneitials");
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer bf6dcfd4e975a007dc8184be6bcf580c'); //Authorization details needed

    return xhr;
}
```

The problem is that this is always sent as an OPTIONS call, which the server does not handle at all. If I remove

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer bf6dcfd4e975a007dc8184be6bcf580c');
```

then it becomes a GET request but the server will not process it without the access token.

Is there a way to send the Authorization Header in the GET request ?

Or will I have to modify the server to handle OPTIONS requests ? I.e. preflights and so forth.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an Authorization header then you are making a complex request and you have to handle the OPTIONS preflight before the browser will make the GET request.

You can't set the header without handling the OPTIONS request.

Comment: I was hoping that was not the case. Thank you Quentin for confirming my fears.